# My foo.js works in Django runserver but in Apache (wsgi) i get 404. Why?

Tags: python, django, apache, url, routes

Every url works fine in both Apache and django runserver except for urls (pointing to views, not real files) like this:

```
foo.js
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^foo.js$', 'myapp.views.foo', name="foo"),
```

**views.py:**

```
def foo(request):
    return HttpResponse("foo")
```

In **development server** calling this url outputs me `foo`

In **Apache** with mod_wsgi, with the same url i get `404`

**wsgi conf file** (really basic):

```
import os
import sys, logging

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

path = '/var/www/vhosts'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.insert(0, path)
   sys.path.insert(0, path + '/myapp')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Classic urls like `/foo/` work as expected.

Where is the problem? Is it an apache behaviour that i don't know / recognize? Is it Django routing?

**edit**:

After adding apache conf (thanks for the maybe obvious hint), i think that those AliasMatch on *.js are the problem.. i completely forgot them!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/myapp"
        ServerName www.myapp.local


    Alias /robots.txt  /var/www/vhosts/myapp/public/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/vhosts/myapp/public/static/favicon.ico

    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /var/www/vhosts/myapp/public/static/$1
    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.js)  /var/www/vhosts/myapp/public/static/$1


    Alias /media/  /var/www/vhosts/myapp/public/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/myapp/public/static/

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/myapp>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess myapp.djangoserver processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp.djangoserver

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/myapp/apache/django.wsgi
LogLevel info
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What does the Apache conf look like?

Comment: i forgot that the vhost conf was not so "standard".. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set up Apache to serve the directories set as `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` at `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL`, respectively? In development, Django serves the static media for you so you don't need a full webserver stack, but in production, it's up to you to serve the files.

**UPDATE**

Just remove the `AliasMatch` lines. They're unnecessary if you've already set up `Alias` directives for both /media/ and /static/. All static resources will be in one of those two directories.

Also, don't forget to run `python manage.py collectstatic`. Otherwise, the directory specified as `STATIC_ROOT` will be empty, which would obviously also result in 404s.